# Neovim - Start LSP only on first insert

Tags: neovim

I use Tmux and auto-session to auto restore all of my Neovim sessions. I don’t want the LSP to start up for a project I’m not editing yet - to save memory and CPU

On first InsertEnter I want to start the LSP and it should keep running for a while as normal

How can I configure this?

—-

Also, after a timeout of user activity for say 30 mins, I want the LSP to stop until the next InsertEnter

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in following steps:

- First things first, disable *LSP* server autostart, set *autostart*
  to *false* in your lsp setup methods, like this:

```lua
lsp_config.bashls.setup({
    autostart = false,
    ... rest of configuration
})
```

- Launch only relevant *LSP* server on *InsertEnter* event with example
  for *bashls*:

  Create autocommands for launch of *LSP* server

```lua
local group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("lsp-tricks", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("InsertEnter", {
    pattern = { "*.sh" },
    callback = function(ev)
        -- logic to start lsp server, be sure to not start multiple instances
        -- at once, check neovim api
        -- possible command to start server vim.cmd([[ :LspStart bashls ]])
    end,
    group = group 
})
```

- Shutdown *LSP* server after inactivity

  You are only limited by *lua* :), one of options is to create some kind of a mark (write to a file timestamp etc...) each time you try to start a lsp server and recheck it somehow in lua or to bind such checks to another neovim event.

Useful neovim help to read:

- *:h autocommand*
- *:h lsp*